# How to get to the specific position on scrollview based on subview id?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to create an app that can save strings of messages from users, and I am displaying that messages in a `UIView` that will go inside a `UIScrollView`. Now, Once these views are created, they have a message id that is associated with it. Suppose that I tap a link that contains a message id, I want the app to redirect me to the specific location in the scrollview when the view of the message is located. Anyone knows to do that?

btw, I used this code to assign message id's to the views:

```
- (void) getMessageId:(UIScrollView*) scrollView{
CGPoint point = CGPointMake( scrollView.contentOffset.x + 40, 20);
for ( UIView* childView in scrollView.subviews ) {
    if ( [childView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] ) {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([childView frame], point)) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , childView.tag] forKey:@"current_message"];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Since I have multiple subviews inside the scrollview (depending on the number of messages), I want to START the view in that specific location of the message (not to load the only particular message ALONE)

Can I do that using `[self.scrollView viewWithTag:messageId]`?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this. take one array with all the message id's which are in
same order as a the scrollview subviews(displaying order of messages on scrollview) ,whenever click on link find
the position of the message id in array and by using message id you
can set contentOffset value to the scrollview.